# TextView string dissappears after updating

Tags: android, string, kotlin, textview

I have the following TextView

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cookieCount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black />
```

and I programatically update it to say this

```
cookieCount.text = """${vm.cookies} cookies"""
```

vm.cookies gets updated every second, and so does this code. Everything works fine, however once the cookies are 10 or above the "cookies" part of the string disappears leaving only the integer. What could be causing this and how can I fix this bug?

Comment: If you ask me, I'd say that behavior is pretty strange. Some more information would be helpful though. For instance, what view group or layout contains this text view? Again, it's strange since you say you're updating the text attribute and not adding new text views to the group.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `layout_width` to `match_parent` and update the layout around to support it. Alternatively you could try to use `ellipsize="end"` which will add the three dots at the end if entire text no longer fits in the measured width.

In any case it's bad for performance to have `wrap_content` and update text periodically as this triggers a bunch of re-measuring under the hood.

Also: Why the triple double quotes when `"${vm.cookies} cookies"` will do?